# How to explicitly call the ASP.NET json serializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

So I have a small asp.net app which returns Json objects that are serialized from C# objects. If I just create a function:

```
[HttpGet(getTheObj)]
public SomeObj GetTheObject()
{
    return new SomeObj() { SomeProperty = 1 };
}
```

Then it works fine and I can do an HttpRequest for the Json object. However I also want to save some these serialized objects into a database for later use. So I'm wondering, can I explicitly call the Json serializer? I understand that several different serializers can be used with ASP.NET, how do I figure out which one I am using (I didn't create the project).

Answer (score 1):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data.ToArray());
```

you can save this in database. you can again retrive this object from database and deserialize this object.